# Using sub-interfaces in overriden functions of sub-classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

Hello dear OOP experts,

I am sorry in advance if this question has been asked before, I haven't been able to find any similar issue (I may not have the appropriate words to explain).

In order to make a flexible system, I am trying to use `Interfaces` and `Abstract` classes. The involved entities are pretty simple:

```
public interface IAbilityTarget
{
    // A bunch of properties and functions
}

public interface IDamagable : IAbilityTarget
{
    int Life { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Ability
{
    public abstract bool CanBeUsed( IAbilityTarget[] targets );
    public abstract void Use( IAbilityTarget[] targets );
}    

public class Fireball : Ability
{
    public override bool CanBeUsed( IDamagable[] targets )
    {
        return true ; // for the sake of the example
    }

    public override void Use( IDamagable[] targets )
    {
        for( int index = 0 ; index < targets.Length ; ++index )
            targets[index].Life -= 1 ;
    }
}
```

My question is the following : Why do I have `CS0115` errors?

> error CS0115: `Fireball.CanBeUsed(IDamagable[])' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

Since `IDamagable` extends `IAbilityTarget`, I don't see why I get the error. I don't feel like implementing the following in `Fireball` to avoid the error:

```
public override bool CanBeUsed( IAbilityTarget[] targets )
{
    return true;
}
public bool CanBeUsed( IDamagable[] targets )
{
    return CanBeUsed( (IAbilityTarget[]) targets );
}
```

What changes I have to make in order to avoid the error, without having to overload `CanBeUsed` for each sub-interface.

Comment: IDamagable is more specialised than IAbilityTarget. Specifying IAbilityTarget in the abstract class means that implementors can only be sure that members of IAbilityTarget are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since IDamagable extends IAbilityTarget, I don't see why I get the error.

Here's a situation where an inconsistency would arise if your `Use` method in `Fireball` did override the `Use` method in `Ability`.

```
class MyDummyTarget : IAbilityTarget { ... }

...

Ability myAbility = new Fireball();
myAbility.Use(new IAbilityTarget[] { new MyDummyTarget() });
```

From the compiler's point of view, this should work: `myAbility.Use` requires an `IAbilityTarget[]`, which you have given it. However, because of overriding, `myAbility.Use` calls the method defined in `Fireball`, which accepts an `IDamagable[]`. Now, how can your `MyDummyTarget` object inside the array be converted to an `IDamagable`? There is no way.

You need to change your parameter types so that both methods' parameter types are the same. Either make them both accept a `IAbilityTarget[]` or `IDamagable[]`. I think the former might make more sense.

From your other comment:

> Sure, but in the Fireball::Use() function, I want to decrease the life, but this property is defined in the IDamageable interface only !

You can do it like this:

```
public override void Use( IAbilityTarget[] targets )
{
    for( int index = 0 ; index < targets.Length ; ++index ) {
        if (targets[index] is IDamagable) {
            ((IDamagable)targets[index]).Life -= 1 ;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a more type-safe approach,

```
public abstract class Ability<T> where T : IAbilityTarget
{
    public abstract bool CanBeUsed( T[] targets );
    public abstract void Use( T[] targets );
}    

public class Fireball : Ability<IDamagable>
{
    public override bool CanBeUsed( IDamagable[] targets )
    {
        return true ; // for the sake of the example
    }

    public override void Use( IDamagable[] targets )
    {
        for( int index = 0 ; index < targets.Length ; ++index )
            targets[index].Life -= 1 ;
    }
}
```

But this prevents you from converting `Ability<IAbilityTarget>` to `Ability<IDamagable>`.

Sometimes you just have to accept the limitations of the type system.

Comment: Why would `myAbility.Use` call the method defined in Fireball since `myAbility` has been defined as an `Ability`? http://rextester.com/JZTDJ35159

Comment: @Hellium Does the `Use` method in `Ability` have a body? No. What do you expect to happen when an abstract method is called? Remember at runtime `mAbility` is an object of `Fireball`.

Comment: `Does the Use method in Ability have a body? No`, but what if I wanted something to happen in this function?

Comment: @Hellium I just had a look at your link. You should note how your link is different from the code presented in your question. In your link, you did not use the `override` keyword so methods are not overridden. But here, you are trying to make `Fireball.Use` override `Ability.Use`.

Comment: @Hellium Did the implementation I provided in the edit solve your problem?

Comment: I guess it will, but I loose the "type validation" at compile time when calling `Fireball::Use`, since I don't want anything but an array of `IDamageable` to be passed as parameter. By allowing an `IAbilityTarget` array, programmers using my code could pass whatever object implementing `IAbilityTarget` to the function, which would not have any effect (because of the type checking in `Fireball::Use`)

Comment: @Hellium I added a more type safe approach.

Comment: I like the Generic approach! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You're `Fireball` violates the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Because a client with a reference to `Ability` can pass an array of `IAbilityTarget` to each of its methods.

But if the underlying (runtime) type of that reference is really a `Fireball` those objects passed to the methods must implement `IDamagable` which is a stricter requirement. Ie. you cannot substitute a `Fireball` for an `Ability` without changing the way methods are called.

Generally overrides must be *less* strict in what pre-conditions they require (not use the types, but any state of the passed objects). You're being *more* restrictive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I suspected, but I also tried to have the following `Ability::CanBeUsed( IDamagable[] targets ) /* */ Fireball::CanBeUsed( IAbilityTarget[] targets )` and the result was the same, and it's logical because `Fireball::CanBeUsed` may need a function only accessible in the `IDamageable` interface.

Comment: @Hellium There are limits to what one can achieve within the limited static type system of languages like C#. You either have to refactor the types so you don't need covariance, or you end up with runtime checks.